# LL(1) table-driven (non-recursive) generator

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, generator, ll-grammar

Please, need help. I'm searching for a LL(1) table-driven (non-recursive) generator. Can't find anything on Internet. All I found is a bunch of LR or recursive parsing generators :( Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some searching since [LL(1) table-driven compilers with ANTLR or ANTLR3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9893058/1243762) and found several pages in one of my old compiler books. ["The Theory and Practice of Compiler Writing"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0070651612) by Tremblay and Sorenson. 1985

It predates the dragon books.

Section 6-2 is 38 pages.

```
6-2 Top-Down Parsing with No Backup
6-2.1 Notions of Parsing with No Backup
6-2.2 Simple LL(1) Grammars
6-2.3 LL(1) Grammars without e-Rules
6-2.4 LL(1) Grammars with e-Rules
6-2.5 Error Handling for LL(1) Parsers
```

EDIT

Found this: [LL(1) Parser Applet](http://ag-kastens.uni-paderborn.de/lehre/material/compiler/parsdemo/ll1frame.html)

EDIT

You might be able to find a copy of "The Theory and Practice of Compiler Writing" in a near by library using [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/title/theory-and-practice-of-compiler-writing/oclc/11398039&referer=brief_results)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I'm looking for a generator to speed up the coding process.